# Finding "func main" in a stripped binary written in GO

Tags: binary-analysis, binary, ghidra, x86-64

I'm reversing a binary that was apart of a CTF I was involved in about a month ago. It was too large of a binary to do during the challenge so I am doing it now.

I am having trouble finding the *main function* because the entry function is not the same as if this was written in C and compiled with GCC. I was wondering how I could go about finding the main function and if there were any resources that could assist me in my endeavors.

Comment: Wrote an article about this a bit back and maintain an IDA plugin that resolves the function names, it could be a good starting point for you; https://rednaga.io/2016/09/21/reversing_go_binaries_like_a_pro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some plugins that does the functions renaming for go language (and others as well). For example [this one](https://github.com/ghidraninja/ghidra_scripts) could be used and after renaming bunch of methods can be seen:
[image]

Comment: Cool! I'll try that out! Thank you :)